# Trying to set output of input to format with commas, but output returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

When I type a comma into the input field, the output immediately returns a NaN. I have verified that the output is a string type, yet NaN is still returned. Ideally, the math is calculated and the output returns a formatted version. Here is a CodePen example of my issue: https://codepen.io/jreednexio/pen/WNYxVJG

```js
const input1 = document.getElementById("amount");
const output1 = document.getElementById("output1");

function calculate() {
  let test = Math.trunc((2.2 / 100) * input1.value);
  console.log(typeof test);
  let text = test.toString();
  console.log(typeof text);
  output1.innerHTML = text;
}
input1.addEventListener("input", calculate);
```

```html
<input
  id="amount"
  name="amount"
  type="text"
  maxlength="12"
  value=""
  placeholder="123,000"
  oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,'');"
/>
<div id="output1">0</div>
```

Comment: You probably don't want two `oninput` handlers (via both `oninput` and `addEventListener`). Try removing the `oninput` from the `<input>` tag, then change `calculate` to do the regex replace, instead of trying to process the input in two different `input` handlers.

Comment: Working example: https://codepen.io/bduffs/pen/xxQOvMQ - just not sure if this is what you want. Are you trying to strip the commas as the user types, or do you just want to ignore the commas when computing the equation?

Comment: @Brandon My eventual goal is to take the input EX: "100,000,000" and the output will display "220,000". I was running into the NaN issue, however, you seem to have fixed that.

Comment: To format with commas, check out `Intl.NumberFormat`. For example: `new Intl.NumberFormat().format(1234); // returns "1,234"`

Comment: In this line: `let test = Math.trunc((2.2 / 100) * input1.value);` The `input1.value` is still a string so the result is `NaN` convert it into a float: `parseFloat(input1.value)`.